# Detech if user has touched edges of a View

Tags: android

I am trying to create a game, and I have a circle now I want to detect if a user has touched the edges of the circle.

It does need to be code even an explanation on how to do it would be great, but if there would be code it would be appreciated :D

This is the example:

[image]

Visual Aid on what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I want to detect if the user has touched the `TOP LEFT, TOP RIGHT, BOTTOM LEFT, and BOTTOM RIGHT` portions of the circle.

This is what I have done so far:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x=(int)event.getX();
    int y=(int)event.getY();

  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

  if (x < boxX){
  touchDirection = "LEFT";
  }

  else if (x > boxX){
   touchDirection = "RIGHT";
  }


 //NOT WORKING
 else if (x < boxX && y > boxY){
 touchDirection = "TOP LEFT";
 }

 else if (x > boxX && y > boxY){
 touchDirection = "TOP RIGHT";
 }

 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: What are boxX and boxY?

Comment: @user5954246 Sorry I knew I forgot to add something ahah. It is the touch coordinates of the user :D Added it into my question, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: you just have to compare the coordinates, what is your actual problem?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Hey sir yup, I already found my answer my logic was just wrong needed to change some values and got it working! I was just overcomplicating things haha

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x=(int)event.getX();
    int y=(int)event.getY();

   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

   if(y > boxY)    touchDirection.append("TOP");
   else             touchDirection.append("BOTTOM");
   if (x < boxX){
   touchDirection.append(" LEFT");
   }
   else {
      touchDirection.append(" RIGHT");
  }

}
```

Assuming touchDirection is `StringBuilder`

Sorry I didnt format, it is hard to do in mobile app

Comment: Hey sir I got the answer and posted it. I was just overcomplicating things and finally got the logic right. Thanks again for the help! :D I wanted to give you an upvote but sucks i need 15 rep. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x < boxX){
  touchDirection = "LEFT";
  }
else if (x < boxX && y > boxY){
     touchDirection = "TOP LEFT";
}
```

First condition will never allow you to check whatever you've written in `else if` block. Whether it finds `x < boxX` is true it's not going to the next condition to check 'y > boxY'. My advice is to using only if conditions for each and every case. Like this:

```
if (x < boxX){
  touchDirection = "LEFT";
  }

if (x > boxX){
   touchDirection = "RIGHT";
  }

if (x < boxX && y > boxY){
 touchDirection = "TOP LEFT";
 }

if (x > boxX && y > boxY){
 touchDirection = "TOP RIGHT";
 }
```

PS: As I can't replicate your case my answer is based on unimplemented logic. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey sir I got the answer and posted it. I was just overcomplicating things and finally got the logic right. Thanks again for the help! :D I wanted to give you an upvote but sucks i need 15 rep. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found my answer already, thanks to **user5954246** and **WS Ayan** for providing help in finding the answer to my problem.

Basically this is what I did:

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x=(int)event.getX();
    int y=(int)event.getY();

 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if (x <= boxX && y >= boxY){
                touchDirection = "BOTTOM LEFT";
            }


            if (x >= boxX && y >= boxY){
                touchDirection = "BOTTOM RIGHT";
            }


           if (x <= boxX && y <= boxY){
                touchDirection = "TOP LEFT";
            }


           if (x >= boxX && y <= boxY){
                touchDirection = "TOP RIGHT";
            }
            }
```